# Как произвести такой ввод в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list

Помогите сделать ввод чтобы элементы ввода находились сразу же после строки и чтобы элементы, которые будут введены были добавлены в массивы.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

print('Введите количество элементов в множествах Х и Y:')
elementsX = int(input())
elementsY = int(input())

print('Введите элементы множества X:')
for i in range(elementsX):
    list1.append(input())
print('Введите соответствие:')
for i in range(list1):
    print(i, '>', list2.append(input())
```

Вывод должен быть что-то типа:

```
x1 > y1
x2 > y2
x3 > y3
...
xn > yn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

print('Введите количество элементов в множествах Х и Y:')
elementsX = int(input('Введите количество Х-в и Y-в: '))
#elementsY = int(input('Введите количество Y-в: '))

print('Введите элементы множества X:')
for i in range(elementsX):
    list1.append(input(f'X-{i+1}: '))
    
print('Введите соответствие элемент множества Y:')
for i in range(elementsX):  #(list1):
    list2.append(input(f'Y-{i+1}: '))

print()
for i in range(elementsX):    
    print(f'x{i+1} = {list1[i]}, y{i+1} = {list2[i]}')
```

Comment: так, ок, хорошо, огромное спасибо, но теперь я понимаю что не знаю как с этим правильно работать, постараюсь объяснить, поставлена задача что на вход программа получает два множества и соответствие между этими множествами и нужно указать есть ли это соответствие отображением(правильно заданным), я пытался найти вариант как можно задать это соответствие, нашел, но теперь не могу понять как действовать дальше

Comment: @Иван вы задали вопрос, показали что вы хотите получить, Вам предложили несколько вариантов решения. Если какой-то из ответов решил вашу текущую проблему, то не забудьте пометить тот ответ как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас возникают другие проблема - задайте новый вопрос, приложите пример кода и доходчиво объясните что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 0):

можно проще:

```py
data_dict = {}

elements_length = int(input())

for _ in range(elements_length):
    key = input('Введите элемент множества X: ')
    value = input('Введите элемент множества Y: ')
    data_dict[key] = value

for key, value in data_dict.items():
    print(f'{key} > {value}'
```

но если вам нужен именно ваш вариант, то:

```py
list2 = []

print('Введите количество элементов в множествах Х та Y:')
elementsX = int(input())
elementsY = int(input())

print('Введите элементы множества X: ')

for i in range(elementsX):
    list1.append(input())

print('Введите соответствие: ')

for i in range(list1):
    element = input()
    list2.append(element)
    print(f'{i} > {element})
```

Comment: Появляется такая ошибка: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: так, ок, хорошо, огромное спасибо, но теперь я понимаю что не знаю как с этим правильно работать, постараюсь объяснить, поставлена задача что на вход программа получает два множества и соответствие между этими множествами и нужно указать есть ли это соответствие отображением(правильно заданным), я пытался найти вариант как можно задать это соответствие, нашел, но теперь не могу понять как действовать дальше